# Updated APK in Google play store have not reached the mobile phones

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have published my updated apk in Google play store console. 
After few hours I see the updated apk in Google play store site. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.shakthydoss.thirukural&hl=en

However I did not see the updates happening in mobile phones that have installed my previous version. I believe Google play store will push the new updates automatically to all mobile that have older version.

Any idea why updates have not reached on mobiles that have older version of app. Or is there any time frame that I have to wait till.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you update your app, you should increment its version code by 1, did you increment the version number ?
i can see in google-play that :

last Updated April 10, 2015 and version number : 2.0

Comment: Yes I did. Earlier it was android:versionCode="1" and android:versionName="1.0". Then I changed to android:versionCode="2" and android:versionName="2.0" after that only i published.